# What Can I Do When the Floating Window Is Not Displayed Normally in My Game?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

"Recently, my team integrated the Game Service SDK and APIs related to the floating window to their app according to the official documentation.

But when they packaged and ran the app, the floating window was not displayed normally.
How can I fix it?"

Comment: Hi Sujith, there could be a lot of reasons that can potentially cause this issue like actual procedures and setups, device model, os, language, sdk version, location, geographic, etc.. Please provide more info. regarding those plus your new code snippet so I can help further. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The official documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/game-buoy-0000001050121528?ha_source=hms1) give instructions on how to integrate the floating window function:

[image]

- For Huawei devices running EMUI 9.1.1 or later, you do not need to integrate any SDK, the game floating window is automatically displayed.
- For Huawei devices running EMUI earlier than 9.1.1, you need to integrate the floating window function following instructions at the preceding link.

1. If the following floating window is displayed, the integration is successful.

   [image]
2. If the floating window cannot be displayed, perform a check based on the following items.

- Game   initialization API：The `init`  API must be called before calling APIs related to the game floating window.
- Calls   of APIs related to the floating window：Call the `showFloatWindow`  API in the `onResume` method and   call the `hideFloatWindow` API in   the `onPause` method. For details,   please refer to the official documentation.
- Logic   for calling the floating window API：The `hideFloatWindow`   API can be called only after the `showFloatWindow`   API has been called to display the game floating window on the game UI.
- HUAWEI   AppGallery version number on the test device：The AppGallery version must be 9.0 or later.

For Detail,pls kindly refer:**[What Can I Do When the Floating Window Is Not Displayed Normally in My Game?](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0203417554929060009?fid=0101188387844930001)**